# How to get a response from a matched pattern in Seneca?

Tags: node.js, microservices, seneca

I wonder what is the best way to get a response from a service that matches the request pattern in Seneca? or maybe the receiver should not send an ACK to the publisher. To be more specific I want to get a response from a service that sends an email to the user to be sure that my email was sent.
What is the best practice for this situation?

Seneca [here!!](http://senecajs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This is built-in - use seneca.client() and seneca.listen() with synchronous messages: https://github.com/rjrodger/seneca-examples/tree/master/micro-services

Unless you are trying to use a non-seneca service? In that case it is dependent on the response from that service.